# Recovery plan from tennis shoulder

Tags: recovery, shoulders, tennis

Shoulder pain is caused by the assisting movement of tennis when you os humerus moves 2 cm outward from the normal position in each assist.

The rubber band is my first choice. 
However, I do not have it many times in my training trips.

I do push-ups with hands close to the body often. 
This feels good in the shoulder.

**Is there any other movements which you can do recover from tennis shoulder without the rubber band?**

Comment: You might want to explain what you mean by "tennis" shoulder.

Comment: Shoulder pain caused by the assisting movement of tennis when you os humerus moves 2 cm outward from the normal position in each assist.

Answer (score 1):

You should try "foam roller", I have used it personally for my shoulder injury (caused by a gym accident, and had to rest it for a whole month before I actually start doing any type of athletic activities) with tremendous results.